# Como restringir formatos no textbox do c#

Tags: c#, validação, textbox

sou novo em programação e tenho talvez uma dúvida muito simples.
Eu estou fazendo um trabalho prático na faculdade e em 4 textbox devem ser tratadas as consistências das notas e eu queria restringir o textbox para que não aceitasse esse formato de nota ("010"). e se caso o usuário digite entre 1 e 9 adicione um ",0" (tirando o número 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se deseja que apenas se digite números pode atribuir um evento ao textbox.KeyPress para tratar isso. Então marcar o tamanho máximo de caracteres para restringir o número de dígitos.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.MaxLength = 2;
        textBox1.KeyPress += textBox1_KeyPress;
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '\b'))
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Bom no caso de validar usando o evento Validating do TextBox, segue abaixo:

```
    private void textBox2_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        var tbx = (TextBox)sender;
        var txt = tbx.Text.Trim();

        //tamanho superior a tantos digitos..
        if (txt.Length > 3)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Altertar que digitou muitos digitos?!");
        }
        //algo não é número
        else if (txt.Any(w => !char.IsNumber(w)))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Altertar que digitou algo que não é número?!");
        }
        //inicia com zero e tem outros numeros
        else if (txt.StartsWith("0") && txt.Any(w => "123456789".Contains(w)))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Altertar que digitou zero antes de algum outro número?!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: não eu queria que se o usuário fosse mudar pra outra textbox essa validação proibisse ele de digitar a nota nesse formato tipo: nota: 010

Comment: editei a resposta, assim talvez?

Comment: sim, era isso mesmo!